# How to workaround non existent types in Graphql query in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I'm building a website with a blog section, and on deployment to production the blog will be empty. I'm having problems allowing an empty blog on my Gatsby site.

When I run `npm run develop` it will only work if I have some blogs - I want it to work before the blogs have been added.

The main issues I'm encountering is trying to accomidate fields not existing like `allStrapiBlog` and `strapiBlog` because there are no blogs.

I get errors like this on `blog` components, and on my `nav` component (where i have a query that a conditional uses).

```
  15:17  error  Cannot query field "allStrapiBlog" on type "Query"  graphql/template-strings
```

```
Cannot query field "strapiBlog" on type "Query"
```

This is what the query looks like for my navigation component. But it throws an error - is there a way to make it just return `null`?

```
query NavigationQuery {
    allStrapiBlog {
        nodes {
            title
            strapi_id
        }
        totalCount
    }
}
```

How do I make unsuccessful GraphQL queries not break the build, so I can build a gatsby site with a empty blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it throws an error - is there a way to make it just return `null`?

Indeed, you need to [configure your GraphQL schema](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/) to allow nullable fields.

You have a boilerplate that you can tweak to match your data types at https://www.virtualbadge.io/blog-articles/nullable-relational-fields-strapi-gatsbyjs-graphql.

The idea relies on using the `createSchemaCustomization` API in your `gatsbt-node.js` to add your own type definitions.

Something like:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typeDefs = `
    type StrapiBlogPost implements Node {
      title: String!
      content: String
      thumbnail: File
    }
  `;
  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

In this case, the `title` is required (because of the `!`, which means that the type is [non-nullable)](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#:%7E:text=means%20that%20the%20field%20is,an%20array%20of%20Episode%20objects.) while `content` and `thumbnail` can be null.

Afterward, you will only need to adapt your component to avoid code-breaking logics when null data is fetched.